# Can I ask Flow questions from external users?

Tags: community, external

We would like to be able to ask questions from external users through a Flow if possible. Ideally, we would be sending an email with a link in it and have them answer a couple questions, and Submit. We would create a new record of a custom object.

What do we need to do to allow an external user to do this ? We have Community licenses, but we don't use them for this. These external users wouldn't have any kind of SF license (be it Community or otherwise). Is there a way we could somehow utilize a designated Community license for this ? Or is there another way this could be done ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the use case you are describing can be best handled through Salesforce Surveys. Surveys will allow you to send questions to external users l, record those responses back to your data model in Salesforce and it also gives you some cool customization ability such as survey translations based on the user’s preferred language.

You could also accomplish this with other tools similar to Salesforce surveys, I just mentioned it because I’m familiar with it.

Handling this through a flow wouldn’t be possible for external users.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much @cloudtrooper

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect. You can expose a flow to external users through a visualforce page. It also has to do with the context the flow runs in.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_flow_guestuser.htm&type=5

And also, see:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_vf.htm&type=5

Setting a flow-to-system context can expose data to the public, so be careful when doing this.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_system_mode.htm&type=5

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/198004)

Comment: Good point! Thank for you for the feedback on my answer.